# What Rx tool should I use for returning to UI only one observable from continuous Rx stream (actually, PublishSubject)?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have `PublishSubject`, which emits new item once new message received from Service (it runs a background thread with open socket connection and send/receive message from server and, once message received, sends localbroadcast with received message).
When UI needs to make call to server and get some data from response, I filter stream of incoming messages to receive only one expected message (each message have unique ID, so it's easy). So here is simplified code I have:

```
public Observable<ResponseType> getStuff() {
    Request request = new Request()
    messageSender.send(request);

    AsyncSubject<ResponseType> subject = AsyncSubject.create()

    inStream.filter(response -> response.hasId())
            .filter(response -> response.getId() == request.getId());
            .subscribe(response -> {
                subject.onNext(response);
                subject.onComplete();
            }, error -> { subject.onError(error) });
}
```

So... As I can't understand some things.

1. Will implicit observable die after subject receive one message and complete?
2. Using AsyncSubject for emitting only one item is bad, but I don't know any alternatives.

What Rx class should I use for notifying UI about response? I heard about Single<>, but I have no idea about how to insert it in my code.

What better mechanism should I learn for stream filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Find two solutions:

- `Observable#first()`
- `Observable#toSingle()`

Resolved.